# How to load proxy rig in version 3

Tags: animation, rigging

Blender version 3. The new version seems to have changed the way proxy-rig is loaded. I don't see the "make proxy" command. Please tell me how to load proxy rig in version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [library override](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html) rather than a proxy.

In your source/library file put the armature and the mesh objects in a collection.
In your destination file, link the collection and use a library override.  *Immediately* after linking the collection use Object -> Relations -> Make Overide.

Comment: Marty Fouts, thank you very much! It works. In version 2.93 I had to disable visibility in the original rig file. Otherwise in my animation scene the rig armature was grayed out and could not be highlighted. In this version 3.0 this does not need to be done. Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could help.